# RxJs. Why a subject emits only once after mergeMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a few links, which one represents a user's active order. When a user clicks on it, I want to send an HTTP DELETE request to an API. I have a function in my component ts file, which get called from my template like so:

```js
// Component
interface CancelCommand {
    orderId: string
}
private cancelCommands = new Subject<CancelCommand>();

/* Get called from a template on click, like so 
          <a ... (nzOnConfirm)="cancel(ord.id)">Cancel</a> */
cancel(orderId: string) {
    this.cancelCommands.next({
        orderId: orderId
    })
}
```

I'm subscribing to the Subject `cancelCommands`  in my `ngOnInit`:

```js
// Component
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cancelSub = this.cancelCommands.pipe(
        mergeMap((command) => this.service.cancelOrder(command)))
    ).subscribe()
}
```

In the service the `cancelOrder` function just calling HttpClient

```js
// The Service
cancelOrder(command: CancelCommand) : Observable<CommandResponse> {
      return this.http.delete<CommandResponse>(`${this.url}/${command.orderId}`)
}
```

My question is, why does the observable with `this.cancelSub` subscription stops emitting values after first order's cancellation?

Comment: This is most likely due to the http.delete completes and closes the subscription. In this case i would use a switchMap it create a new observable for you for each delete request

Comment: I'd recoment to use a full observer in subscribe() and log the events - then you know if an error happened or if complete was called. You should anyway have a handler for the error-case.

Comment: @TmTron, I've HTTP error handling in the interceptor and in the catchError (which I've omitted for the question's simplicity)  but thank you for pointing out on the 'complete'.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1se9yc?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Obviously if the observable errors out or completes, the subscription would be closed. Try to check if any such occurs.

Comment: I can not replicate the error as well. At the same time I am wondering why don't you go for a simpler approach, like having the `cancel` method call directly the `cancelOrder` service method rather than `next`ing the `cancelCommands` Subject?

Comment: @MichaelD thank you for your help! The problem was in error handling.  If you're interested it was like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m684sd?file=src/app/data.service.ts

Comment: @Picci thank you for your help! The problem was in the error handling. I've included stackblitz example above, if you're interested. Answering your question, I need a subject because I also have a button like "Cancel all". It makes multiple calls to the backend for each order.

Comment: @PilgrimViis: You seem to explicitly throw an error based on a condition. If an observable emits an `error`, it's closed thereafter, akin to a `complete` emission. In fact, `error` and `complete` are exclusive. Do you wish to carry on the subscription even after throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys for your tips! With your help, I've figured it out. The error happened when one of my requests return an error and the observable stops. I've fixed it like this, looks like it's ok.

```js
    this.cancelSub = this.cancelCommands.pipe(
      mergeMap((command) => this.service.cancelOrder(command)),
      catchError((_, caught) => caught) // new line
    ).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

@PilgrimViis Have you checked if the observable this.cancelSub really completes?

@TmTron I checked if mergeMap completes when the source observable completes which is not the case here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qthnmy?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

Comment: yeah, because in your case, the inner observable never completes. I was referring the the OPs code, where the inner observable (the http delete request) will complete.